# Generate such an Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have a basic question. Is there a way to define an *Elliptic Curve* over (binary) Finite Field of order $q=2^m$ such that by taking the points from $(0, Y_0)$ and $(1, Y_1)$ then maps them to $(q - 1, Y_{q - 1})$?

Comment: Do you mean an EC can contain all tuples as point?

Comment: @kelalaka yes, something like that. That for all points (Xi,Yi) for each i from 0 to q-1 Xi = i

Comment: Do you mean; the EC has $q^2$ points which are $(0,0),(1,0),\ldots,(q-1,0),\ldots,(q-1,0),(q-1,1),\ldots,(q-1)$ and with the point at infinity, total poins is $q^2+1$.

Comment: I mean that there may be any number of points but for X there should be values from 0 to q with no matter values of Y.

Comment: Remember for any $x$ there can be at most two $y$, i.e. $(x,y)$ and $(x,-y)$. Therefore the number of points cannot pass $2q+1$ where 1 is the point at infinity. Your question is not clear to have an answer. Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: So is your question, whether for any suitable $m$ one can find an elliptic curve over $2^m$ such that for all $m$ with $0\leq m<2^m$ there exists $y_m$ such that $(m,y_m)$ are on the curve? Formulated differently, whether there exists an elliptic curve so that we can immediately map any string to a valid x-coordinate?

Comment: @SEJPM An interesting work [Elliptic Curves with a Given Number of Points](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221451662_Elliptic_Curves_with_a_Given_Number_of_Points)